# How can I load config values from AWS secretsmanager when using node-convict?

Tags: node.js, configuration, aws-secrets-manager

I've got a node app that is loading env-striped configurations using [`node-convict`](https://github.com/mozilla/node-convict). For things like tokens, I'd like to load them through the same config system, where I can specify dev tokens in the dev config file, but for other environments the value will be in AWS secrets-manager.

Ideally I would just hook a method in so that node-convict calls my method to fetch the secret value, but I don't see an easy way to inject that into the config schema.

Before I go and create a bunch of code to do this, I wanted to know if there's an easy way to do this that I've missed? Seems like it would be a common usecase by now. Is there another env-striping config npm library I should be using for this instead?

I see there was an attempt to add something along these lines, but it doesn't look like it made it into node-convict 6: https://github.com/mozilla/node-convict/pull/342